# typescript generic parameter constructor as parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, constructor, builder

classX.ts

```
export class ClassX{}
```

I have this non-generic code:

```
import { ClassX } from './classX';
function buildY() {
  return doSomthing({
    constructorMethod: ClassX,
  });
}
```

which I want to make it generic:

```
function buildY<T extends { new(): T ;}>() {
  return doSomthing({
    constructorMethod: T,
  });
}
```

The new generic builder ussage:

```
import { ClassX } from './classX';
const classYInstance = buildY<ClassX>();
```

but TS complains with the following error:

> 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

How could I fix this TS error?

Comment: Could you make this a [mre] without undeclared/undefined types?  I don't know what `classX` is.

Comment: Your non-generic version gets the `classX` constructor by importing it.  When you turn it generic, from where do you plan to get the constructor?

Comment: The recursive constraint `T extends { new(): T }` cannot mean what you want it to mean; you're saying that `T` is the type of a constructor that constructs instances of type `T` itself... which is the type of a constructor that constructs instances which are constructors that construct constructors constructing other constructors and... . If I had a value `t` of type `T` I could write `new (new (new (new t())())())()`. If you want `T` to be an instance than you just need `T extends object`; if you want it to be a constructor then you just need `T extends { new(): object }`.

Comment: @jcalz updated the post. I need to pass the generic class constructor method as a non-generic argument to `doSomthing` method and I don't want to change `doSomthing` method.

Comment: And what is `doSomthing()`?  I'd love to see an actual [mre] here suitable for pasting into an IDE without having to guess at what these things are doing.  My *guess* here is that the answer will look something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKyVyN), but without something concrete from you about `doSomthing()` I can't be sure.

Comment: @jcalz something like that but my code complains with the error I put in the description above. The difference is in the minimal reproducible example you shared, you passed ctor as a parameter while I want to infer it from the generic type T instead.

Comment: Forgive me for being repetitive, but could you please [edit] the code in the question, so that if I take that code and paste it into an IDE, I can reproduce the issue you're seeing without having unrelated problems? Right now I don't know what `doSomthing` is or what it returns, so I'd just have to guess, which isn't a great position to be in. I know that any answer I give will require you to make the call like `buildY(ClassX)` instead of `buildY<ClassX>()`, but in order to be specific about what that looks like, I need a reproducible example. reproducible example. reproducible. echo.